# How can I turn on alpha/beta testing for a Google Home Action?

Tags: actions-on-google

There is no Alpha/Beta testing options in the Release tab of the Google Actions console.

I'm developing a Google Action (Smart Home). I can test it with my developer account, and can invite others to test as developers (ref: https://medium.com/@rekire/alpha-test-your-action-on-google-5886246e0e).

But I could not find the Alpha/Beta releases as documented in https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments

There is only a Production section in the Release tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha/Beta channels aren't available for Smart Home actions.